# Laravel Mysql error inserting £ sign (Incorrect string value: '\xA327.20...')

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, utf8mb4

I am using laravel to import some .txt files into the database.

The contents of the file would be:

`Amount due is £27.20`

I am able to obtain the contents of the file using

`$record[contents] = Storage::disk('dropbox')->get('/file.txt')`

I then insert it into the db using the following

`Document::create($record)`

However when trying to insert this data into the database, I get the following error

`SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect string value: '\xA327.20...'`

I understand it is something to do with encoding of the £ sign but cannot figure out how to fix it. My database was previously set to latin1_swedish_ci

I therefore charged the relevant column collation to utf8mb4_general_ci however I am still seeing the same error.

Comment: Please show your insert code

Comment: Edited with insert code. This part of it works fine as it works fine when the txt files do not contain any 'special symbols'